# Xamarin.Android C#, stuck at SQLiteConnection(dbpath). Null Exception, Object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Here is the Code:

```
    public long AddCase(Customer addCust)
    {
        using (var db1 = new SQLiteConnection(_helper.WritableDatabase.Path)) //Null Exception:Error
        {
            try
            {
                return db1.Insert(addCust);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //catch Exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to invoke the above function with the code below

```
DatabaseUpdates ManageDb = new DatabaseUpdates();
ManageDb.SetContext(this);

DatabaseUpdates upd = new DatabaseUpdates();

upd.UpdateCustomer(var);
Name.Text = "";
```

.
.
I have a function to check if _helper is null or not..,

```
if (context != null)
            {
                _helper = new DataManagerHelper(context);
            }
```

Well I want to know what actually SQLiteConnection(dbpath) means. Why its showing null Exception. I know the concept why it declares null exception. Please help me understand why the below code gives me an error,

```
**using (var db1 = new SQLiteConnection(_helper.WritableDatabase.Path)) //Null Exception:Error**
```

No build errors. There are debug errors.
Please help

Comment: Its not duplicate. If you really find it duplicate then please help me how it is a duplicate. Please help me understand that error

Comment: Either _helper is null or _helper.WritableDatabase is null, or Path is null and the error occurs in the sqliteconnection constructor

Comment: Hmmm.. Thank you @bro. Well I need a solution for that. I am even trying to understand that SQLiteOpenHelper function too